# Return an array to post into the $_SESSION in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, session, session-variables

I have a form with inputs using Checkbox, I have named them all as an array name="benefits[]"

This is filled into a jquery to use as part of Chain Selects.

My question is how can I put the array into the $_SESSION so that whichever checkbox is selected I can use this in another input box on another page within my site?

```
<input type="checkbox" class="comOne" name="benefits[]" value="Pension credit" id="pension_credit" /> 
Pension credit 
<a href="#" class="showBenefitInfo" data-value="Pension credit is a top-up to the state pension and is a benefit that must be applied for if your state pension is below a certain amount.">[More...]</a>
```

Apologies if I shouldn't have done this, wasn't sure if you could upload a text box, anyway this is the whole section of code for the checkboxes. If needs be I could paste the whole form.

> ```
>                             <div class="row">
>                                 <div class="col-md-5">  
>                                     <label class="checkbox">
>                                         <input type="checkbox" class="comOne" name="benefits[]" value="Pension credit" id="pension_credit" /> Pension credit <a href="#" class="showBenefitInfo" data-value="Pension credit is a top-up to the state pension and is a benefit that must be applied for if your state pension is below a certain amount.">[More...]</a>
>                                     </label>
>                                 </div>
>                                 <div class="col-md-5">  
>                                     <label class="checkbox">
>                                         <input type="checkbox" class="comOne" rel="CTC"  name="benefits[]" value="Child tax credit" id="child_tax_credit" /> Child tax credit <a href="#" class="showBenefitInfo" data-value="Child Tax Credit is a benefit that must be applied for, it is not the same as Child Benefit. An up-to-date Child Tax Credit award notice must be available to show the surveyor to proceed with your application. ">[More...]</a>
>                                     </label>
>                                 </div>
>                             </div>
>                             <div class="row">
>                                 <div class="col-md-5">  
>                                     <label class="checkbox">
>                                         <input type="checkbox" class="comOne" rel="ISJSA" name="benefits[]" value="Income support" id="income_support" /> Income support <a href="#" class="showBenefitInfo" data-value="Income support is a means-tested benefit and is primarily received by single parents with a child under 5.">[More...]</a>
>                                     </label>
>                                 </div>
>                                 <div class="col-md-6">  
>                                     <label class="checkbox">
>                                         <input type="checkbox" class="comOne" rel="ISJSA" name="benefits[]" value="Job seekers allowance" id="job_seekers_allowance" /> Income based job seekers allowance <a href="#" class="showBenefitInfo" data-value="You must be in receipt of INCOME based job seekers allowance. This will be confirmed on your award notice (you will see printed on your letter: 'This assessment is based on how much the law says you need to live on').">[More...]</a>
>                                     </label>
>                                 </div>
>                             </div>
>                             <div class="row">
>                                 <div class="col-md-5">  
>                                     <label class="checkbox">
>                                         <input type="checkbox" class="comOne" rel="WTC" name="benefits[]" value="Working tax credit" id="working_tax_credit" /> Working tax credit <a href="#" class="showBenefitInfo" data-value="You will need to have you Working Tax Credit award notice available (this will be the same as Child Tax Credit award notice if both are being received). Page 2 and 3 will confirm your household income and this MUST be less than &pound;15,860 to qualify.">[More...]</a>
>                                     </label>
>                                 </div>
>                                 <div class="col-md-6">  
>                                     <label class="checkbox">
>                                         <input type="checkbox" class="comOne" rel="ESA" name="benefits[]" value="Income related employment" id="income_related" /> Income related employment and support allowance <a href="#" class="showBenefitInfo" data-value="Also known as ESA, Employment and Support Allowance must be INCOME related and NOT contribution based. This will be confirmed on your ESA award notice.">[More...]</a>
>                                     </label>
>                                 </div>
>                             </div> 
>                             <div class="row">
>                                 <hr>
>                                     <div class="col-md-12">
>                                         <label class="checkbox">
>                                             <input type="checkbox" class="comOne" name="benefits[]" value="I do NOT receive any of the above benefits" id="no_benefits" /> I do NOT receive any of the above benefits 
>                                         </label>
>                                     </div>
>                                 </hr>
>                             </div>
> ```

Comment: If there are multiple checkboxes it would be advisable to use indices as well to identify exactly which checkbox is checked, i.e. `"name=benefits[<id>]"`.

Comment: so use a number like name="benfits[1]" etc or use the id that is in the input also as an example I have "id="pension_credit" so use name=benefits"[pension_credit]"? also what would happen doing this as the jquery uses benefits[] to see which checkbox is used?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty straight forward:

```
$_SESSION['benefits'] = $_POST['benefits'];
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that first before posting. this is what I had on my page I wanted it to show in the input box. It returns Array in the input box on my other page

Comment: Did you put `session_start()` at the top of all the pages you wish to use sessions on? That's the only thing that would prevent this from working.

Comment: You should update this question with the code for both pages as this is basic PHP and should work. Maybe we an spot the problem.